# Why the following async function works exceptionally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read about the behaviors of `async` functions from some answers on this site. But still I'm confused. I tried 2 jQuery statements, of which **STMT1** 'co-operates' with ajax call, while STMT2 doesn't. What I mean is `ajax` statement can't get the required **data**.

Why is it so? Does **STMT1** executes little faster than the **STMT2**?

EDIT: By behavior, I mean `async` statements execute together, they are non blocking. So my both statements shouldn't work? But still one of them is working. Why is it so?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var foo='types: ';
    $("button").click(function(){
        //STMT1

        // $("p").each(function(){
        //  foo=foo+$(this).text();
        // });

        //STMT2

        $("p").hide(function(){
            foo="YOLO";
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'name='+foo,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Couldn't make request");
            }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What behavior are you seeing? What behavior do you expect instead?

Comment: I edited the detail.

Comment: It's still not clear. What is "working" that you don't expect to be working? What isn't working (which apparently you expect)?

Comment: I mean the `ajax` statement is getting the value of `foo`, which I think shouldn't because all 3 statements execute irrespective of each other as they are async? Does it work by a coicidence that STMT1 executes enough fast so that ajax gets the value?

Comment: And is there some possibility that I won't get value from STMT1 when connection is slow or some other problem, as `ajax` doesn't wait for it?

Answer (score -1):

jquery animations are async methods, and default duration for hide method is 400ms

source - http://api.jquery.com/hide/

and that's why your ajax request goes first and variable foo gets changed later. hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Your `hide` callback will run **later**, not right away, when jQuery finishes hiding the element with the default delay (400ms). So `foo` isn't changed before you *start* the following ajax call. If you want to wait until `foo` is changed to start the following ajax call, put that call *inside* the `hide` callback.

> I mean the ajax statement is getting the value of foo, which I think shouldn't because all 3 statements execute irrespective of each other as they are async? Does it work by a coicidence that STMT1 executes enough fast so that ajax gets the value?

No, it's not coincidence at all. Your four async calls are **not** all running in parallel, only two of them are. Here's what's happening in that code:

1. You schedule a `ready` callback
2. Some time later, the `ready` callback is fired:

   1. It assigns a value to `foo` (`var foo='types: '`).
   2. It sets up a `click` handler
3. **If** you click the element, then:

   1. The click handler schedules a `hide` with the default delay
   2. It starts the ajax call, using `foo`'s existing value (`"types: "`).
   3. About 400ms later, `hide`'s callback is run, setting `foo`'s value to `"YOLO"`
4. If you click the element again, it does the same thing, but this time `foo`'s value is already `"YOLO"` so that's what's used by the ajax call

Comment: Please reply my comments. My doubt is how ajax getting value of STMT1?

Comment: Does ajax statement waits for STMT1? Or they execute together? I mean when only STMT1 is available for ajax.

Comment: @VikasKumar: The ajax call doesn't wait for the `hide` callback, no. It does wait for the call to `hide` (which *starts* the hiding process, but doesn't finish it) to finish, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if there's no hide function. I'm talking about the first statement and ajax call. How they work? I'm getting the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133146/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-t-j-crowder).